# How to customize sender for Meteor Accounts' password reset mail

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

How can I customize the sender for password reset mail sent by [Meteor Accounts](https://www.meteor.com/accounts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender used by Meteor Accounts when sending password reset mail is controlled by the `Accounts.emailTemplates.sender` attribute. Just assign your desired value to it on server startup, for example:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "Admin <no-reply@example.com>"
})
```